# substring function to separate two strings using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have strings like X,Y. I want to separate X from Y using javascript. Please describe how to as I am new at javascript

Comment: Please elaborate on your requirements. Are the two strings X and Y concatenated? Are you looking for a way to split a string into two (e.g. "MyHome" into "My" and "Home" ? Or do you want a substring method such that substring("MyHome",2) return "Home" ?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp). You would use it like this:

```
a = "X,Y"
b = a.split(",")
```

This would create an array of the strings "X" and "Y" and put that in b.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method on a string, which will split the string into a array:

```
var myString = "X,Y";
var myArray = myString.split ( "," );
```

myArray will then contain "X" on index 0, and Y on index 1

Or you could use the [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) method as so:

```
var myString = "X,Y";
var myX = myString.substring ( 0, myString.indexOf ( "," ) );
var myY = myString.substring ( myString.indexOf ( "," ) + 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var Test= "X,Y";
var Part = Test.slice(0, 1);
```

or

```
var Test = "X,Y";
var Part = Test.substr(0, 1);
```

Comment: He didn't ask to split it always on the position where the "," is, he asked how to get a substring.